# WPF binding a combobox to an array/list of business objects

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I'm building a WPF application and my UI consists of combobox and about a dozen other UI controls.  I have a single business object class that contains a dozen or so properties and implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Here's a snippet of my business object:

```
public class MyBusinessObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }

    private int _idNumber;
    public int IdNumber
    {
        get { return _idNumber; }
        set
        {
            if (_idNumber == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _idNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IdNumber"));
        }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }

    private int _age;
    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set
        {
            if (_age == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _age = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Age"));
        }
    }

    private string _address;
    public string Address
    {
        get { return _address; }
        set
        {
            if (_address == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _address = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Address"));
        }
    }

    private bool _employed;
    public bool Employed
    {
        get { return _employed; }
        set
        {
            if (_employed == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _employed = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Employed"));
        }
    }

    public MyBusinessObject(int idNumber)
    {
        this.IdNumber = idNumber;
        // set default values here
    }
}
```

As you might expect, the various UI controls will be bound to the properties of my business object.  However, I need to create an array or list of business objects (10 of them to be specific) and bind my combobox to the IdNumber property.  So my user will select the object that they want from the combobox and then the other UI controls should update to display the values for each of their bound properties for the selected object.

Right now, I just have one instance of my business object declared in my code behind like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // this will be replaced with an array/list of business objects
    MyBusinessObject myObject = new MyBusinessObject(1234); // 1234 = IdNumber

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = myObject;
    }
}
```

And currently, my combobox is defined like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="selectedObjectComboBox" IsEditable="False"/>
```

Once I implement my array/list of business objects, can anyone tell me how I would bind the combobox to the array so that it will display the IdNumber for each object?  Also, what, if anything, will I need to do to get the other bound controls to reflect the values of the selected object when the user changes their selection in the combobox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to bind your `ComboBox` to your list, then use the `DisplayMemberPath` to specify which member you want displayed:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding yourList} DisplayMemberPath="IdNumber"/>
```

If you want your other controls to update off of this value, you might want to consider making a `SelectedItem` property on your view model and bind the selected item to this. Then your other controls can bind to this.

*EDIT*

That can be achieved by doing something like:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding yourList} SelectedItem={Binding SelectedBusinessObject} DisplayMemberPath="IdNumber"/>
```

If you don't want to make a backing field, you could do something like..

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding yourList} x:Name="BusinessComboBox" DisplayMemberPath="IdNumber"/>
<MyControl Item={Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=BusinessComboBox />
```

Comment: it should be property IdNumber not field idNumber.

Comment: @gleng Thanks for the reply.  I've created a List<MyBusinessObject>, set my data context accordingly and updated the combobox per your response.  The combobox is now displaying the name of all 10 of my objects but changing the selected object isn't causing the other UI controls to display the values.  All of my existing control bindings are still pointing to properties like this:  {Binding Age} or {Binding Address}.  Do those need bindings need to be changed now that I'm using an array of objects instead of a single object?

Comment: @gleng Thanks again for the updated answer.  It's pointed me in the right direction, I think.